# Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist in React native IOS build

Tags: ios, react-native

I am new at React Native and am receiving a compile-time warning when I run `react-native run-ios`.

```
Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/OneModelPlace.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
```

I have set some configuration in Xcode but don't want to use `react native upgrade`. Is there any other way to run my project?

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things I try when this happen:

1. Close your simulator, close your packager.
2. `rm -rf node_modules && yarn`
3. `rm -rf ios/build`
4. Remove Xcode derived data (path available in **Xcode** > **Preferences** > **Locations**)
5. `react-native run-ios`

Answer (score 0):

I did **following things** which solved my issue

- Opened my project in  Xcode
- Compiled and cleaned my project
- Remove any external library if that causes you a problem in a build
- rebuild your project and run your project with Xcode
- And you are done